# Likelihood Ratio Test for Cox Models in R

Tags: r, cox-regression

Does anyone know of a likelihood ratio test, like lrtest in the lmtest package, that works for cox proportional hazards models produced using coxph?  lrtest does not seem to work for coxph models.

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

There is an `anova.coxph` in pkg:survival which allows comparison of model objects.

```
fit <- coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ resid.ds *rx + ecog.ps, data = ovarian) 
fit2 <- coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ resid.ds +rx + ecog.ps, data=ovarian)
anova(fit2,fit)

Analysis of Deviance Table
 Cox model: response is  Surv(futime, fustat)
 Model 1: ~ resid.ds + rx + ecog.ps
 Model 2: ~ resid.ds * rx + ecog.ps
   loglik  Chisq Df P(>|Chi|) 
1 -31.970                    
2 -30.946 2.0469  1    0.1525
```

This is an LR test.

w.r.t. the comment. A "null model" in Cox regression would be formed with only a `1` on the RHS of the formula-tilde:

```
fit <- coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ 1, data = ovarian)
```

Comment: In the above case, which Model is the null model?  Thank you.

Comment: I would call Model 1 the "base" model. I reserve the term "null model" for those which have just an "intercept" on the RHS. Model 2 (`=fit`) in this case has the extra term formed by the interaction which is 1 in cases where both `resid.ds` and `rx` are not the base factor level.

Answer (score 2):

LR-Test is returned by default by `coxph()` from thr survival package (see last line):

```
require(survival)
test1 <- list(time=c(4,3,1,1,2,2,3), 
              status=c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0), 
              x=c(0,2,1,1,1,0,0), 
              sex=c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1)) 
# Fit a stratified model 
coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ x + strata(sex), test1) 

Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ x + strata(sex), data = test1)


   coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z    p
x 0.802      2.23    0.822 0.976 0.33

Likelihood ratio test=1.09  on 1 df, p=0.297  n= 7, number of events= 5
```

Comment: Is there any way I can get a 95%CI for the LR test?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941746/how-to-get-95-ci-from-rs-coxph