# How to get 95% CI from R's coxph?

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I have used the following function in R's coxph() to fit a cox hazard model. I want to report the proper statistics; however, there is no 95% CI in the output.

`Surv(days, censor) ~  gender + age + treatment, data_1)`

I only get the following columns.

`coef exp(coef)  se(coef)     z       p`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A simple way to get confidence intervals for the hazard ratios associated with your predictor variables would be to use the "summary" function on your model fit.  If you want confidence intervals for the coefficient estimates themselves you could use the "confint" function.  Exponentiation of the results from confint can also be used to get the hazard ratio confidence intervals.

```
fit <- coxph(Surv(t,y) ~ x)
summary(fit)  #output provides HR CIs
confint(fit)  #coefficient CIs
exp(confint(fit))  #Also HR CIs
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need this for further processing, consider a `tidy` solution with `broom`:

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
library(survival)

mod <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex + age, data = lung)

mod |> 
  tidy(conf.int = TRUE, exponentiate = TRUE) |> 
  select(term, estimate, starts_with("conf"))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   term  estimate conf.low conf.high
#>   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 sex      0.599    0.431     0.831
#> 2 age      1.02     0.999     1.04
```

More details at [this reference](https://github.com/pavopax/gists/blob/master/survival-in-R.md#details-1)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply find <s>`CI`</s> `conf.int` in `CoxPH` model summary in `R` ( in case using `survival` package . Its under `lower .95` and `upper .95`

Update 2019 (But I assume the suggestion did not work previously):

```
test1 <- list(time=c(4,3,1,1,2,2,3), 
              status=c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0), 
              x=c(0,2,1,1,1,0,0), 
              sex=c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1)) 
# Fit a stratified model 
coxobj <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ x + strata(sex), test1) 
coxobj_summary <- summary(coxobj)
coxobj_summary$conf.int
```

Output:

```
   exp(coef)  exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
x   2.230706   0.4482887 0.4450758  11.18022
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked a while ago. However, I figured this solution here might come in handy for those wanting to have a function arranging the `summary(coxobj)$coefficients` and `summary(coxobj)$conf.int` outputs and doing some publication-friendly adjustments for further output processing.

```
library(dplyr)
library(survival)

# Fit a model using the lung dataset
coxobj <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex + age, data = lung)

#--------------------------------
# Set up a function doing the work
# #1 cbind summaries for coefficients and conf.int
# #2 make it a df
# #3 select the cols of interest (all except exp(coef) & exp(-coef) from conf.int)
# #4 re-arrange the CI cols next to the HR col
# #5 format digits cols 1:6 -> 2 digits & col 7 (p-values) -> 3 digits
# #6 set colnames using pipe structure
#--------------------------------
fun_coxreg <- function (coxobj) {
coxtable1 <- cbind(summary(coxobj)$coefficients, summary(coxobj)$conf.int) %>% #1
  as.data.frame () %>% #2
  select (c(1:5, 8:9)) %>% #3
  relocate (`lower .95`, .after = `exp(coef)`) %>% #4
  relocate (`upper .95`, .after = `lower .95`) %>% #4
  mutate (across(1:6, .fns = function(x) {format(round(x, 2), nsmall = 2)})) %>% #5
  mutate (across(7, .fns = function(x) {format(round(x, 3), nsmall = 3)})) %>% #5
  `colnames<-` (c("Coefficient", "Hazard Ratio (HR)", "HR (lower 95%CI)", "HR (upper 95%CI)", "SE coefficient", "z", "p-value")) %>% #6
return ()
}

# Apply function & return result
coxtable <- fun_coxreg(coxobj)
coxtable

    Coefficient Hazard Ratio (HR) HR (lower 95%CI) HR (upper 95%CI) SE coefficient     z p-value
sex       -0.51              0.60             0.43             0.83           0.17 -3.06   0.002
age        0.02              1.02             1.00             1.04           0.01  1.85   0.065
```