# Bootstrap for Mediation Confidence Interval

Tags: r, bootstrap-4, confidence-interval

I am fitting this regression in R to assess mediation:

```
#weighted cox model

fitYcox <- coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ const(factor(exp))+const(factor(expstar)) +
           covariates, data=newmyd, weights=newmyd$weightM)
```

and computed the Total effect (TE), Direct effect (DE), Indirect effect (IE), and Proportion mediated(PM) as follow:

```
#return value

TE = exp(sum(coef(fitYcox)[c('const(factor(exp))1','const(factor(expstar))1')]))

DE = exp(unname(coef(fitYcox)['const(factor(exp))1']))

IE = exp(sum(coef(fitYcox)[c('const(factor(expstar))1')]))

PM = log(IE)/log(TE)
```

Can anyone help compute a bootstrap 95% CI for TE, DE, IE, and PM? Thank you!

Comment: I left flag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941746/how-to-get-95-ci-from-rs-coxph

Comment: This is different from my question